# When adding this function through "My Custom Functions", I get "Fatal error"

Tags: php, function

I'm attempting to use this bootsnip: https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/pjQ4E with the Wordpress Plugin "My Custom Functions".

However, I get the error "Sorry, but your code causes a "Fatal error", so it is not applied!
Please, check the code and try again."

It happens with all functions I try to add from Bootsnip.com. The contents of this particular snippet is:

```
$(function() {

function toggleChevron(e) {
    $(e.target)
            .prev('.panel-heading')
            .find("i")
            .toggleClass('rotate-icon');
    $('.panel-body.animated').toggleClass('zoomIn zoomOut');
}

$('#accordion').on('hide.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
$('#accordion').on('show.bs.collapse', toggleChevron);
})
```

The example works fine at bootsnip, but when trying to add in My Custom Functions plugin, get the error as stated. I've also tried adding it in functions.php and it crashes the site.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/my-custom-functions/) for My Custom Functions:

> An easy to use, with intuitive interface, WordPress plugin that gives you the ability to easily and safely add your custom functions (**PHP code**) for execution in WordPress environment directly out of your WordPress Admin area, without the need to have an external editor.

The code you are trying to add is **JavaScript**, it is not **PHP**.

---

You can add the script to your `header.php` template file.

See [the WordPress Codex page on using JavaScript](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) for other options.

Comment: Haahaa... Okay. Thank you Quentin.